# Uniqueness of generated with Crypto.generateAesKey(128)

Tags: apex, crypto

I want to generate a unique text for integration purposes using the following code fragment.

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
String key = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(cryptoKey);
```

I tested this with 10000 iterations and the keys generated seems to be unique. 
 
Is it safe to assume that it will be always unique?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61795/calculate-all-possible-keys-for-aes-128-encryption-to-exploit-hardware-encryptio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general purposes, the chance of you getting a duplicate string should be acceptably low.

Technically, it will eventually generate duplicate output. The chance of a duplicate will (should?) increase if you truncate the key.

So the answer is "no, it will not *always* be unique, but that's probably something you don't need to worry about".